# Nexio USB IR touchscreen issues

Tags: 12.10, touchscreen

I have USB Nexio Touchscreen attached to my Dell Inspirion M2300. Ubuntu 12.10 Desktop.

xinput and lsusb correctly lists out the touchscreen as "iNexio iNexio USB" but there is no response on using the touchscreen.

Running evtest and xinput calibrate does not return anything as the touchscreen doesn't seem to be responding to touch.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same.

Few monts ago i got it working by installing 3.6 kernel to 12.10, yet it needed this trick to work:

when the desktop is loaded touch the screen and see the cursor in one of the corners of the screen, no matter where you touch the cursor is always in that corner, if this happens, restart X and it should work properly.

if you cant see the cursor when touching then restarting X wont help. sometimes lsusb did not list the device

Comment: try to download nexios official installation package for linux form their site: http://www.inexio.co.kr/07_download/download02.html and read the manual http://www.inexio.co.kr/pdf/manual/Linux%20Manual_ENG.pdf